# How to generate random longitude and latitude?

Tags: javascript

I need to generate some random longitude and latitude like `39.21988,9.124741`.

I tried:

```
function getRandomInRange(from, to, fixed) {
    return (Math.random() * (to - from) + from).toFixed(fixed) * 1;
}
for(var i =0; i<4; i++) {
 console.log(getRandomInRange(-180, 180, 3));
}
```

But the result is:

```
-107.237
5.533
-118.927
90.629
```

While I'd need them comma separated every 2 so it should be:

```
-107.237,5.533
-118.927,90.629
```

Comment: Just loop only twice, and perform two calls to `getRandomInRange` inside the loop?

Comment: @trincot you mean with a nested for loop?

Comment: Please note that "it is incorrect to select spherical coordinates theta and phi from uniform distributions theta in [0,2pi) and phi in [0,pi], since the area element dΩ=sinφdθdφ; is a function of φ, and hence points picked in this way will be "bunched" near the poles" ref: [Sphere Point Picking](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html).

Comment: @AndrewMorton ye I know about haversine, I was just wanting to quickly generate some coords, but if You can do the same but including the formula would be great, as I was looking around and just couldn't find a solution for this question including the haversine too in js

Comment: What's the problem here? `getRandomInRange()` returns a number. You need two, separated by `,`. As this is only possible with a string. Create two numbers, convert them into strings, and then concatenate them. JS is friendly enough to do all the "hard" work for you if there's at least _one_ string...

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @Andreas i did research, was just some stupid confusion, that's all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this solve your issue:

```js
function getRandomInRange(from, to, fixed) {
    return parseFloat((Math.random() * (to - from) + from).toFixed(fixed));
}

var latLongPairs = 4;

for(var i =0; i<latLongPairs; i++) {
 console.log(`${getRandomInRange(-180, 180, 3)}, ${getRandomInRange(-180, 180, 3)}`);
}
```